# Solutions to $m^2 = x^2 - y^2$ if $m \in N$ under additional conditions.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Is it true that if $m \in N$ is odd and $m > 1$ has $d$ number of different factors that are bigger than $1$, then there are **at least *d*** number of different pairs $(x_i, y_i) \in N\times (N \setminus \{0\}), 1 \le i \le d$ that would satisfy the $m^2 = x^2 - y^2$ equation?

Comment: No, take $m = 1$.

Comment: There are $\lfloor \frac{d}{2} \rfloor$ different pairs, I think.

Comment: Why can $x$ be zero but not $y$?

Comment: Still no. Take $m=3$. ($3$ has two divisors and the equation has one solution $(x,y) =(5,4)$ )

Comment: @jjagmath I've corrected again, now it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this equation, on can see that
$$m^2= x^2-y^2 \Longleftrightarrow m^2=(x-y)(x+y)$$
m^2
Let $q_1,\dots,q_d$ be $d$ different factors of $m$, and let $r_1,\dots,r_d$ be such that $q_i\times r_i = m$. . Then we can find $x$ and $y$ such that
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc}x+y = r_i.m \\ x-y=q_i\end{array}\right.$$
namely :
$$\left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} x&=&\dfrac{q_i+r_i.m}{2} \\ y &=& \dfrac{r_i.m-q_i}{2} \\ \end{array}\right.$$
As $m$ is odd, all of its factors are odd, therefore $q_i+r_i.m$ and $r_i.m-q_i$ are even, and the $x$ and $y$ we found are integers. We still have to show that : $y$ is positive ; for $i \neq j$, the couples $(x_i,y_i)=(\dfrac{q_i+r_i.m}{2},\dfrac{-q_i+r_i.m}{2})$ and $(x_j,y_j)=\dfrac{q_j+r_j.m}{2},\dfrac{-q_j+r_j.m}{2})$ are different.

$\rhd$ If $q_i <m$, then automatically $-q_i+r_i.m >0$. If $q_i = m$, then $r_i=1$ and therefore $y=0$. So the factor $q_i = m$ does not give a solution to your problem, but all of the other factors do.

$\rhd$ If $(x_i,y_i)=(x_j,y_j)$, then as $q_i=x_i-y_i$ and $q_j=x_j-y_j$, we get $q_i=q_j$ and therefore $r_i=r_j$. Thus each different factor of $m$ gives a different solution $(x,y)$.

$\rhd$ Finally, if $m$ has $d$ factors, we found $d-1$ solutions to your problem. If $m$ is prime, one can verify that those are exactly all the solutions of your equation. If $m$ is not prime, there are more solutions. For example, with $m=15=3 \times 5$, the couple $(x,y)=(17,8)$ is the solution with $x+y = 25$ and $x-y=9$, the latter not being a divisor of $15$.

Comment: I think $(0, m)$ is another solution. I don't think it is covered by your definitions of $x$ and $y$. Let $x = 0$, if then $y = m$ in your formula then we would get $m = \frac {r_im - q_1}{2}$ implying that m is an even number as otherwise the fraction would not be a natural number as you've proven before and it would lead to a contradiction requiring $m$ to be even although $m$ was by problem definition odd. So $y \neq m$. However, $(0, m)$ it is still a solution as $m^2 = 0^2 + m^2$. So there should be indeed at least $d$ solutions after all.

Comment: There is a minus sign I think you are missing. For $(0,m)$, we have $x^2-y^2=-m^2 \neq m^2$.

Comment: Oh, you're right, well then we can take $(m, 0)$ instead and apply the same logic? The point $(m, 0)$ is a solution as $m^2 = m^2 - 0^2$ which can't be obtained from your formulas for $x$ and $y$. So it must be an additional solution.

Comment: I agree this is a solution of the equation, but I excluded it from my proof (see the paragraph beginning by "if $q_i<m$ ...") as it was specified "$(x,y) \in \mathbb{N} \times (\mathbb{N} \setminus\{0\})$" in the question.